# How does Ruby evaluate the class of an object when evaluating the truthiness in a condition?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, evaluation

I am trying to make an instance of a class `MyClass` evaluate to a falsy value. So I tried to override all methods I could think of to make `MyClass` act as `nil`. I got:

```
a = MyClass.new
a.nil? #=> true
a.class #=> NilClass
a == nil #=> true
a.eql? nil #=> true
a.equal? nil #=> true
a.instance_of? NilClass #=> true
a.kind_of? NilClass #=> true
a.is_a? NilClass #=> true
```

I even got

```
nil == a #=> true
nil.eql? a  #=> true
nil.equal? a #=> true
```

Finally I tried

```
a.__id__ #=> 4
nil.__id__ #=> 4
a.object_id #=> 4
nil.object_id #=> 4
```

But still, `a` will always evaluate to `true`. So I was wondering how Ruby checks whether `a` is `nil` or `false`. I guess it's something not accessible to the developer.

This is not to solve an actual problem, I am just wondering if it cannot, indeed, be done. I know this would break the Ruby's "everything-ist-true-except-false-and-nil"-idiom, and it would most probably be a purely evil hack.

Comment: No. nikifi wants to know the benefits of that idiom. I want to know, how it is executed and if there is a way to interfere through the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two objects which evaluate falsy. Ruby simply checks whether the object is one of those two. Period.

Note that one of the foundations of OO is simulation: an object can simulate another object. This is not true here: it is impossible to simulate `nil` or `false`. This is one of those annoying cases where Ruby violates OO, very similar to `Object#equal?`.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby checks for actual *value* of an expression.

```
class Foo; end

f = Foo.new
f # => #<Foo:0x007ff3da88b348>

if f
  puts 'yay'
else
  puts 'nay'
end
```

No matter what methods you try to redefine on `Foo` class, `f` will still be an instance of `Foo` and that check will print "yay". Nothing you can do here.